# How to remove space in a list?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project where I am scraping data from Indeed search results. Right now, I am able to print the data that I find, separated by a semicolon, but there is a space between the data and the semicolon.

My data currently prints like this:   `"Item 1 ; Item 2"`

I would like my data to print like this: `"Item 1;Item 2"`

Please let me know what changes I need to make to my code to fix how my data prints. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/nzalle/Downloads/chromedriver")

page = 0
# SearchTerm = input("Search Term: ")
SearchTerm = "EHS"
# LocationSearch = input("Location: ")
LocationSearch = "Arizona"

NumPages = 4
Data = []
for x in range(NumPages + 1):
    url = ('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=' + SearchTerm + '&l=' + LocationSearch + '&start=' + str(page))
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)   # slowdown the loop
    page += 10
    for jobs in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-tn-component='organicJob']"))):
        title = jobs.find_element_by_xpath("./h2/a").text
        try:
            name = jobs.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='company']/a").text
        except:
            name = jobs.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='company']").text
        Data.append(title)
        Data.append(';')
        Data.append(name)
        Data.append("\n")

print(*Data)
driver.close()
```

Comment: using `str.strip()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you printed while unpacking: `print(*Data)`. It creates spaces between items. Proof:

```
print(*['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

```
one two three
```

If you want to concatenate all the strings with no space in between you can use `''.join()`:

```
print(''.join(['one', 'two', 'three']))
```

```
onetwothree
```

But then I'm not entirely sure why you're appending `'\n'` to your list so I might be wrong about what you're doing. You could keep the `'\n'` just for the print statement:

```
print('\n'.join(['one', 'two', 'three']))
```

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: Awesome explanation with `print(''.join(['one', 'two', 'three']))`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `str.strip()` method from class string or `str`. see link here for more details [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20strip#str.strip)

`string.strip(s[, chars])`

> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters
> removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are
> removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters
> in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this
> method is called on.

see fixes inline:

```
for jobs in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-tn-component='organicJob']"))):
        title = jobs.find_element_by_xpath("./h2/a").text
        try:
            name = jobs.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='company']/a").text
        except:
            name = jobs.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='company']").text
        Data.append(title.strip())
        Data.append(';'.strip())
        Data.append(name.strip())
        Data.append("\n")
```